# Does Golang have Pick and Omit feature in structs?

Tags: go

I am currently playing around with Golang and I wonder if it has an Omit and Pick feature similar to typescript.

```
Example in typescript

export type ExampleA = {
      SampleA: string
      SampleB: string
      SampleC: int
      SampleD: []string
      SampleE: boolean
}

export type ExampleB = Omit<ExampleA, "SampleC">
export type ExampleC = Pick<ExampleA, "SampleB">
```

```
Example in golang (just an idea "if" possible via tags)

type ExampleA struct {
      SampleA string `json:"sampleA"`
      SampleB string `json:"sampleB"`
      SampleC string `json:"sampleC"`
      SampleD string `json:"sampleD"`
      SampleE string `json:"sampleE"`
}

type ExampleB struct {
     ExampleA.SampleC `json:"-"`
}

type ExampleC struct {
     ExampleA.SampleB `json:"sampleB"`
}
```

Im not sure if there is an existing implementation of this in Go, but I think this is a good feature.

Comment: It's not possible. But, you can do the opposite: create a composition of structs. In that case: ExampleA{Sample A string, ExampleB, ExampleC, SampleD string, SampleE string}, so ExampleA that uses Example B and ExampleC. If you want just ExampleB you can use it as standalone type.

Comment: @Inkeliz cool! this is great, although it's kind of uncomfortable to see especially let's say you consider ExampleA as your base properties and you just want to pick or exclude some.

This works like a charm thanks this is a great help!

Comment: @ApolloG Try to break the habit of thinking of "base" types when working with Go. Don't think of composition as simply a way to get that behavior. The types should mean something on their own. If you find yourself embedding types everywhere, take a step back and think of why. It's useful but can be overdone.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Go[...] have Pick and Omit feature in structs?

No.

(Rule of thumb: If it isn't mentioned and explained in the Tour of Go: It's not there. And: the language specification is a few pages, easy to read with sensible structure and index.)